# In Redshift, how do I run the opposite of a SUM function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Assuming I have a data table

```
date        |   user_id  | user_last_name | order_id  | is_new_session
------------+------------+----------------+-----------+---------------
 2014-09-01 | A          | B              | 1         | t
 2014-09-01 | A          | B              | 5         | f
 2014-09-02 | A          | B              | 8         | t
 2014-09-01 | B          | B              | 2         | t
 2014-09-02 | B          | test           | 3         | t
 2014-09-03 | B          | test           | 4         | t
 2014-09-04 | B          | test           | 6         | t
 2014-09-04 | B          | test           | 7         | f
 2014-09-05 | B          | test           | 9         | t
 2014-09-05 | B          | test           | 10        | f
```

I want to get another column in Redshift which basically assigns session numbers to each users session. It starts at 1 for the first record for each user and as you move further down, if it encounters a true in the "is_new_session" column, it increments. Stays the same if it encounters a false. If it hits a new user, the value resets to 1. The ideal output for this table would be:

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
4
4
5
5
```

In my mind it's kind of the opposite of a `SUM(1) over (Partition BY user_id, is_new_session ORDER BY user_id, date ASC)`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: In your existing expression, instead of `SUM(1)` you use `SUM(CASE WHEN is_new_session = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` you might get what you're after. (This is in T-SQL - I don't know redshift SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an incremental sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when is_new_session then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by date) as session_number
from t;
```

In Redshift, you might need the windowing clause:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when is_new_session then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by user_id
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
           ) as session_number
from t;
```

Comment: @AkshaySingh, if that worked for you, you might consider accepting the answer so people can see there is a working solution.

Comment: Whoops, first time here. Marked it now.